# Reverse function reverses wrong list

Tags: python

I am really really new to coding and this is my first post but I haven't found anybody else with the same problem yet.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
nr_list = [3, 4, 9]
nr_list_r = []
nr_list_r = nr_list
nr_list_r.reverse()
print(nr_list)
```

It returns `[9, 4, 3]`

I honestly don't know why `nr_list` is reversed when I only used the reverse function on `nr_list_r`.

Why is `nr_list` reversed as well?

Comment: There are two lists, but your two names refer to the same list.

Comment: After `nr_list_r = nr_list`, you have only one list, with two names referring to it.  The reversal of that list is visible via either name.  You would need to copy the list - `nr_list_r = nr_list.copy()` or `nr_list_r = nr_list[:]`.

Comment: `nr_list_r = nr_list` changes what the name refers to. This isn't `C`.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, variables refer to values rather than contain them. So when you do

```
nr_list_r = nr_list
```

You're not making a new list. You're making a new variable refer to the same list. If you want to make a copy, you can use the slice syntax `[:]`

```
nr_list_r = nr_list[:]
```

But we also already have a way to reverse a list without modifying it, so you may as well just do it using that built-in function.

```
nr_list_r = list(reversed(nr_list))
```

We use `reversed` to reverse the iterable and then `list` to convert the result (which is an arbitrary iterable) into a concrete list.

Comment: you can also do: `nr_list_r = nr_list.copy()`

Comment: You can also use list.copy()

Answer (score 0):

Basically with:

`nr_list_r = nr_list`

You are just atributting another name to the list "nr_list"

So when you reverse "nr_list_r" the "nr_list" is gonna get reversed aswell.

In order to reverse just one of them you should copy the list

`nr_list_r = nr_list.copy()`

the full code is like this:

```
nr_list = [3, 4, 9]
nr_list_r = nr_list.copy()
nr_list_r.reverse()
print(nr_list)
print(nr_list_r)
```

Answer (score 0):

The concept of **References** is one of the key optimization in many programming languages.

An object starts its life when it is created. This point of time at least one reference is created.

```
nr_list = [3, 4, 9]  # one reference.
```

As the execution proceeds, more number of references may get created, based on the usage.

```
nr_list_r = nr_list # one more reference added.
```

And also the number of references may be reduced.

```
nr_list_r = [4,6,8] # one reference reduced.
```

Finally the object is considered alive, if there at least one reference exists.

When there are no more references, the object is no more accessible and the memory is reclaimed.